# I want to login to openshift from eclipse

Tags: spring-boot, openshift, spring-rest, openshift-client-tools, openshift-3

I want to connect to openshift from eclipse by using rest client.

By using browser i am able to login, but from elipse(STS) i am getting error.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.openshift.client.OpenShiftEndpointException: Could not request https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api: 




public class AAAAA {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, OpenShiftException, IOException {
        IOpenShiftConnection connection = new OpenShiftConnectionFactory().getConnection("https://console.dev-mds-openshift.mohan.com", "username", "password");

}
}
```

https://console.dev-mds-openshift.mohan.com  is the domain i want to login with my credential.

Comment: Googd to read: https://planet.jboss.org/post/show_domain_info_openshift_java_client_in_a_nutshell

Comment: `openshift.redhat.com` tells me you're using tooling for OpenShift v2 which is deprecated. I'm unfamiliar with Java tooling, so I can't tell you the replacement.

Comment: @WillGordon, please tell me if any other way is there

Comment: @MebinJoe,

I hav tried that, i am getting below error.

Exception in thread "main" com.openshift.client.OpenShiftEndpointException: Could not request https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api:

Comment: @mohan, there's this (https://github.com/openshift/openshift-restclient-java), but I honestly have no idea what you're trying to do, so I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for